# Find equation for a plane orthogonal to two other planes.

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

How to find plane equation which goes through point

```
A(2,1,0)
```

and is orthogonal to the planes

```
x - y + z = 0
```

and

```
2x - 3y + z - 1 = 0
```

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Give us an idea of what you have done to solve your problem. Have you begun by writing the equation $ax+by+cz=d$ with unknown coefficients $a,b,c,d$ ? If you don't answer, you will have no answer on our side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint...the normal to the new plane is the cross product of the normals of the given planes, since it is orthogonal to these. Then use $$\underline{r}\cdot\underline{n}=\underline{a}\cdot\underline{n}$$

Comment: if i use your solution i get normal of (2,1-1) so from ax + by + cz = d i get 2x + y - z = d and d is A(2,1,0) * n(2,1,-1) = 5 so solution is 2x + y - z = 5???

Comment: Yes that's it.;)

Comment: thank you for the solution

Comment: Your'e welcome. You can accept the solution in order to close the question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a plane, through point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ is 
$$
\mathbf{n} \cdot \left( {\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_{\,0} } \right) = 0
$$
where clearly $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$
So if you take $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$, i.e.
$$
\mathbf{n} = \left( {1, - 1,1} \right) \times \left( {2, - 3,1} \right) = \left( {2,1, - 1} \right)
$$
and plug it into the general equation above (with $\mathbf{x}_{\,0}$ having the coordinates of $A$).